# A question on Gersgorin disk

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that the $n$ Gersgorin discs of $A \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ are 
mutually disjoint and $A$ is real.

Why does every eigenvalue of $A$ is real?

Answer (score 3):

The circles must be centered on the real axis if the diagonal in $A$ is real. If they are disjoint it means that no eigenvalues are complex conjugate pairs, but any solution to a polynomial with real coefficients must have its non real roots as complex conjugate pairs, so they must all be real.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in general, each Gershgorin disc may contain one, more than one, or none of the eigenvalues. However, in case the union of some $k$ discs is disjoint from the union of the rest, it is known that the former must contain exactly $k$ eigenvalues and the latter contain the other $n-k$ eigenvalues (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem#Strengthening_of_the_theorem)).

In your case, since all $n$ discs are mutually disjoint, **every disc must contain exactly one eigenvalue**. As these discs are centred on the real axis, no two eigenvalues form a conjugate pair. As indicated by another answer, non real eigenvalues of a real polynomial must occur in conjugate pairs. Hence the assertion follows.

Comment: Yes this is why the proof would not work if any two (or more) circles overlapped as then there could possibly exist at least one complex conjugate pair.